# Python convert OrderedDict saved as string into an actual dict

Tags: python, json, ordereddict

I have a Postgres db where `OrderedDict` has been saved as a string. I need to convert this string into json/dict so that it can be saved in a JSONField. How can I convert this string into dict?

String example -

```
OrderedDict([('order_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('tracking_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('bank_ref_no', 'xxxxx'), ('order_status', 'Success')])
```

I tried `json.loads(string)` but it gives a decoding error. Any solution apart from manually parsing the string?

Comment: `eval(string)` ?

Comment: @furas I generally try to avoid `eval` since it seems unsafe. But in this case I guess it should be okay

Comment: I would also avoid `eval` but using `regex` or `split()` it would need more work and it would not predict all cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `eval` for this purpose.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

x = "OrderedDict([('order_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('tracking_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('bank_ref_no', 'xxxxx'), ('order_status', 'Success')])"

#run string through eval and convert to dict
dct = dict(eval(x))
print(dct)
```

The output will be

```
{'order_id': 'xxxxxx', 'tracking_id': 'xxxxxx', 
'bank_ref_no': 'xxxxx', 'order_status': 'Success'}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you mentioned you want a solution without actual parsing, but the parsing option could be pretty simple too:

```
import ast

a = "OrderedDict([('order_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('tracking_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('bank_ref_no', 'xxxxx'), ('order_status', 'Success')])"

# get the inner list representation
a = a.replace("OrderedDict(", '')
a = a[:-1]

# convert to a list of tuples
x = ast.literal_eval(a)

dict(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use Regex to extract the list and then use `ast` module.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import ast
from collections import OrderedDict

s = """OrderedDict([('order_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('tracking_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('bank_ref_no', 'xxxxx'), ('order_status', 'Success')])"""

print(OrderedDict(ast.literal_eval(re.search(r"(?<=OrderedDict\()(.*)\)$", s).group(1))))
```

**Output:**

```
OrderedDict([('order_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('tracking_id', 'xxxxxx'), ('bank_ref_no', 'xxxxx'), ('order_status', 'Success')])
```